# vaadin 14 @Push annotation required package importation

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I am wondering if someone can explain me which packages to import to match the following example:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/server-push

-onAttach method
-onDetach method

where the message told me that I need to override these methods

Comment: Please paste the exact message into the question. What's with onAttach and onDetach? I don't really udnerstand your question.

Answer (score 3):

These methods are on all `com.vaadin.flow.component.Component` which most UI components extend.  So you should be able to override them on your main route page i.e `VerticalLayout`, `HorizontalLayout`... which all extend `Component`